# MassTransit: Can not receive command from Saga to Consumer [Fixed]

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I have a workflow publishing an event from controller(belongs to `csproj1`) which'll be consumed by `MySaga`(belongs to `.csproj2`), then the Saga when receiving the published message it'll send a new Command that'll be consumed from `CommandConsumer` (belongs to `csproj2`).

### Problem:

Can not receive **command** in `CommandConsumer` while sending it from `MySaga`.

I'm using **Azure Service Bus** and **Consumer Saga**

Here is my `startup.cs` which I think is not well configured:

```cs
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {                
            x.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<CommandConsumer>();            
            x.AddSaga<MySaga>().InMemoryRepository();

            x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString"]);
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
```

Here is `MySaga.cs`

```cs
//...

    public readonly Uri targetEndpoint = new Uri($"queue:{KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance.SanitizeName(nameof(MyCommand))}");

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AceptedEvent> context)
    {
        var sendEndpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint(targetEndpoint);
        await sendEndpoint.Send<MyCommand>(new
        {
            CorrelationId,
            context.Message.Item1,
            context.Message.Item2
        });
    }
//...
```

Here is `CommandConsumer.cs`

```cs
public class CommandConsumer: IConsumer<MyCommand>
{
    public ILogger<MyCommand> _logger { get; }
    public IService _myService { get; }
    public MyCommandConsumer(ILogger<MyCommand> logger, Iservice myService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _myService = myService;
    }
    

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyCommand> context)
    {
        _logger?.LogInformation($"{context.Message.CorrelationId}");            
        try
        {
            await _myService.DoSomething();
            await context.Publish<AcceptedEvent>(new
            {
                CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId.Value,
                State = "NewState"
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await context.Publish<RefusedEvent>(new
            {
                CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId.Value,
                State = "Failed",
                Error = ex.Message
            });
            throw;
        }
     }
}
```

If you have any recommendation ideas thanks for sharing and challenging me!

### Solution:

As @ChrisPatterson mentioned, I used the `Publish` method since I have just one consumer for my command and it works as expected.

More than that I fixed my configuration for `ReceiveEndpoint`:

```cs
var repository = new InMemorySagaRepository<MySaga>();
        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString"]);
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue", cfgEndpoint =>
            {
                cfgEndpoint.Saga<MySaga>(repository);
            });
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance.SanitizeName(nameof(MyCommand)),
                cfgEndpoint =>
                {
                    cfgEndpoint.ConfigureConsumer<CommandConsumer>(context);
                });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The producer is sending to this receive endpoint:

```
public readonly Uri targetEndpoint = 
new Uri($"queue:{KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance.SanitizeName(nameof(MyCommand))}");
```

Which is going to end up being "my-command" based upon how you're using it.

Whereas `ConfigureEndpoints` is going to use the consumer class name for the endpoint, which would be the equivalent of:

```
KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance.Consumer<CommandConsumer>()
```

Which ends up being "command" – so the send endpoint is not sending to the correct address for the consumer.

If that is the only consumer for that command, you could just use `Publish` instead, so that you don't need to know the address of the consumer. Otherwise, you'll need to know the *correct* destination address.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's more clear now I already tested it with `publish` and it works as expected.

Comment: I updated `ReceiveEndpoint` configuration to use the send method with the appropriate address and it works. (**I already updated the post**)